# How to use the User Input node in SPSS modeler?

Tags: spss-modeler

I am trying to make my SPSS flow a bit more dynamic. Although there is no way (that I am aware of) to take an input, is there a way to use User Input node to take some parameter values and use these parameters in another select node to perform tests on data.

What I am trying to achieve is run the same flow with some minor parameter changes. I have the flow running for some static values used in select nodes. It would be great if there was a way to change these static select nodes, even if it's not with a User Input node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is actually to make a parameter in SPSS modeler and then enable/check the **Prompt?** which will ask the user for input every time the stream is executed.

In **SPSS Modeler 18.2 onwards** I was able to see the prompt option as the first feature of parameter tab.